# why xpath cannot get the target element?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am quite new in scraping with xpath. I am trying to scrape product information on Target. I use selenium and xpath successfully get the price and name. But xpath cannot return any value when scraping for product size[product size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jqln.png) and sales location[sales location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZxYQ.png).
For example, for this url"https://www.target.com/p/pataday-once-daily-relief-extra-strength-drops-0-085-fl-oz/-/A-83775159?preselect=81887758#lnk=sametab", xpath for size is:

```
//*[@id="pageBodyContainer"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/text()
```

xpath for sales location is:

```
//*[@id="pageBodyContainer"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span
```

I also try to get these two elements by using requests but it also did not work. Do anyone know why it happened? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Following is my code:

```
    def job_function():
        urlList = ['https://www.target.com/p/pataday-once-daily-relief-extra-strength-drops-0-085-fl-oz/-/A-83775159?preselect=81887758#lnk=sametab',
        'https://www.target.com/p/kleenex-ultra-soft-facial-tissue/-/A-84780536?preselect=12964744#lnk=sametab',
        'https://www.target.com/p/claritin-24-hour-non-drowsy-allergy-relief-tablets-loratadine/-/A-80354268?preselect=14351285#lnk=sametab',
        'https://www.target.com/p/opti-free-pure-moist-rewetting-drops-0-4-fl-oz/-/A-14358641#lnk=sametab'     
        ]
    
        def ScrapingTarget(url):
            AArray = []
            wait_imp = 10
            CO = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            CO.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
            CO.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
            CO.add_argument('--start-maximized')
            wd = webdriver.Chrome(r'D:\chromedriver\chromedriver_win32new\chromedriver_win32 (2)\chromedriver.exe',
                                  options=CO)
    
            wd.get(url)
            wd.implicitly_wait(wait_imp)
            sleep(1)
    
            #start scraping
            name = wd.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='pageBodyContainer']/div[1]/div[1]/h1/span").text
            sleep(0.5)
            price = wd.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='pageBodyContainer']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
            sleep(0.5)
            try:
                size = wd.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='pageBodyContainer']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/text()").text
            except:
                size = "none"
            sleep(0.5)
            try:
                sales location = wd.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='pageBodyContainer']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span").text
            except:
                sales location = "none"
            tz = pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT-0')
            GMT = datetime.now(tz).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    
            AArray.append([name, price, size, sales location, GMT])

            with open(
                    r'C:\Users\12987\PycharmProjects\python\Network\priceingAlgoriCoding\export_Target_dataframe.csv',
                    'a', newline="", encoding='utf-8') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerows(AArray)
    
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
            executor.map(ScrapingTarget, urlList)
    
    sched = BlockingScheduler()
    sched.add_job(job_function,'interval',seconds=60)
    sched.start()
```

Comment: Can you share url to give xpath for your element ?

Comment: @Justin Lambert thanks for the comment. Do you mean xpath for the element? I have edited the question and put a sample url and xapth of the two element  in edited question.

Comment: Remove `/text()` from the xpath of the size. The xpath for sales location works for me